# Swift inout parameter for const properties

Tags: swift, pass-by-reference, inout

Is it possible to use a `let` property with a similar function parameter to `inout` when I do't want to change the property itself but that property's properties?

e.g.

```
let someLine = CAShapeLayer()

func setupLine(inout line:CAShapeLayer, startingPath: CGPath) {
    line.path = startingPath
    line.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    line.fillColor = nil
    line.lineWidth = 1
}

setupLine(&someLine, startingPath: somePath)
```

Also if there is a better way to set up a bunch of properties the same way when they aren't in a loop that would be helpful too.

Comment: You don't need `inout` at all here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CAShapeLayer` is a *class* and therefore a *reference type*.

```
let someLine = CAShapeLayer()
```

is a constant reference to a `CAShapeLayer` object.
You can simply pass this reference to the function
and modify  the properties of the referenced object within the function. There is no need
for the `&` operator or `inout`:

```
func setupLine(line: CAShapeLayer, startingPath: CGPath) {
    line.path = startingPath
    line.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    line.fillColor = nil
    line.lineWidth = 1
}

let someLine = CAShapeLayer()
setupLine(someLine, startingPath: somePath)
```

A possible alternative is a convenience initializer

```
extension CAShapeLayer {
    convenience init(lineWithPath path: CGPath) {
        self.init()
        self.path = path
        self.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        self.fillColor = nil
        self.lineWidth = 1
    }
}
```

so that the layer can be created as

```
let someLine = CAShapeLayer(lineWithPath: somePath)
```

---

A complete example for your playground. Note that it uses default parameters to make it more versatile:

```
import UIKit

class ShapedView: UIView{
    override var layer: CALayer {
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect:CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)).CGPath
        return CAShapeLayer(lineWithPath: path)
    }
}

extension CAShapeLayer {
    convenience init(lineWithPath path: CGPath, strokeColor:UIColor? = .whiteColor(), fillColor:UIColor? = nil, lineWidth:CGFloat = 1) {
        self.init()
        self.path = path
        if let strokeColor = strokeColor { self.strokeColor = strokeColor.CGColor } else {self.strokeColor = nil}
        if let fillColor   = fillColor   { self.fillColor   = fillColor.CGColor   } else {self.fillColor   = nil}
        self.lineWidth     = lineWidth
    }
}


let view = ShapedView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 100, height: 100))
```

result with defaults:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much, totally read the docs wong: Class 'instances' are reference types, Functions are reference types, Everything else is a value type. Thank you for the alternative too!

Comment: This is a perfect example to illustrate, how default values for method parameters come in handy: https://gitlab.com/snippets/20356 @Martin R: Feel free to add this code to your answer if you like to.

Comment: @vikingosegundo: Good suggestion, thanks, but is too late for today :) Feel free to edit this one or add your own answer!